# Joomla Menu In External Page

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to re-create the menu items from main menu in Joomla in a page, which is outside Joomla's template folder.

Are there any method available, such as 'wp_nav_menu' in Wordpress, which would help me to generate the Menu.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to re-create the menu from your Joomla-generated pages for a non-Joomla
page?

Comment: yes, i have a page in another Application, where i need to genertae the menus defined by Joomla Admin

Comment: I think you're going to have to view the source on one of your Joomla pages and cut and paste the menu code from there and hard code it into your non-Joomla application. Make sure you also call the template.css file from your Joomla template as well so that the menu styling matches.

Comment: I am pretty new to Joomla, but all what i can figure out is there is just one liner code in Joomla Template, which renders the required HTML code `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" />`

Comment: you can either hard code it or establish a connection to the database, pull the menu items and echo each result within an `<li>` tag. If you have a dropdown menu then it will be harder. else might be easier to hard code it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two steps that you will need to follow

First, make your external page capable of running joomla library. To do this you will need to include few lines of code in your external php page

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../' );   // should point to joomla root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

Second, Create a menu module for your desired menu and enable it on a custom position say 'xxxx'
and then put the following code where you want the put that menu

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModules('xxxx');
// xxxx is any virtual position, no need to create it anywhere.
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module[0]);
```

Comment: I tried the mentioned code, but it giver me the following fatal error:
`Fatal error: Class 'JModuleHelper' not found`

Comment: put this line before using JModuleHelper  
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
i had also updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Is there in any manner, I could disable the Session Start in Joomla, as it is conflicting with the session used in my application, where I am integrating the Joomla Menu

Comment: I also figured out, we don't need the following line of code, `$mainframe->initialise();`

Comment: I have a site that is build in Joomla, now i have got to integrate another application built earlier with this Joomla installation, so this application is placed under a folder named `app`, at Joomla root. When I create a page in this application to display the menu on the page, it brings `/app/index.php/about` in the menu URL. the expected value is `/index.php/about`