# joomla external php code for login user data

Tags: php, joomla

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php' );
$user = JFactory::getUser();   
echo 'User name: ' . $user->username . '<br />';     
echo 'Real name: ' . $user->name . '<br />';
$specificuser = JFactory::getUser(42);
echo 'Specific User name: ' . $specificuser->username . '<br />';
echo 'Specific Real name: ' . $specificuser->name . '<br />';
```

I have added this code in my external php file. The `$specificuser` code is working; but sometimes the `$user` output is shown, sometimes it isn't.  Any idea of the problem?
output is here:

```
User name: 
Real name: 
Specific User name: user
Specific Real name: Super User
```

Comment: It is PHP and does not have any relation to system you use!search for your conditions in the code

Comment: Make sure that your $user object is not null, otherwise it might be just failing to execute that line and what's below it

Answer (score 2):

`JFactory::getUser()` method loads current user object:

- When you are logged in: it will return your data.
- When you are logged out: you are a guest / anonymous visitor without a name.

Second case also applies when you log in, but your session expires.

Answer (score 1):

You don't start the Joomla! application, so session handling and other things do not work.

See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834582/joomla-2-5-data-retrieve-in-external-php-page/15835166#15835166) for a working example on how to initialize Joomla! correctly.